# Primefaces. Implementation in JSP file

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces

I would like to ask whether it is possible to implement this google map example:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapInfoWindow.jsf
in JSP file. Example shows how to implement that in xhtml file but i need to do this in JSP file. I read JSP files don't support primefaces since x version. Maybe there is other method to implement that map without using primefaces?

Thank you

Comment: Primefaces won't work ofcourse in JSP as it's a solution for JSF, but for JSPs you can do it by hand, I guess that's the best solution for you right now.

Comment: @Developer106 you mean PrimeFaces works on Facelets.

Comment: yes I meant for JSF on Facelets, thanks @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use a JSF component without JSF is analogous to using a Spring bean without the spring framework it set it all up.  Kind of pointless.

That said, simply googling "[google map jsp](http://www.google.com/search?q=map%20jsp#sclient=psy-ab&q=google%20map%20jsp&oq=google%20map%20jsp&gs_l=serp.3...3757.4501.0.4643.7.7.0.0.0.5.362.1468.2-3j2.5.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.i_WHgiNFXGs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.aGc&fp=8b0ac198a01ae30c&biw=1190&bih=779)" brought up some jsp tag libraries which support Google Maps.

http://www.lamatek.com/GoogleMaps/
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Google-Map-Web-Service-With-JSP-2221.php

So, a little leg work might get you somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean in the first sentence. I wonder if it is possible to implement in JSP file because there are a lot of opinions that JSP is no longer valid technology to display JSF components. I visited sites you gave me but when I implemented the first example it does't work for me. There are no errors but after I loaded it on server there is a blank page. I can't see the map. What is more on lematek.com all maps do not load even on example pages.

Comment: JSF is more than the components in isolation.  You need to ensure you're using the JSF framework as part of the servlet which implements the JSF lifecycle, which is what make the components do what they do.  Attempting to use a JSF component outside of the JSF Lifecycle is not possible with re-implementing JSF code.  It should be possible to use JSP pages in JSF (it could, at the start, support both JSP and XHTML pages).  Perhaps it is an issue with Primefaces.  Perhaps it requires xhtml pages.  That said, using xhtml and facelets is, in my opinion, a better option than straight JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to integrate PrimeFaces to jsp files in many different ways, however, I later on learnt that, PrimeFaces tags such as "p:" are only used in JSF(.xhtml) files. If it is not too hard to change the project, try to move it to JSF 2.x or above to be able to use PrimeFaces UI.